# Will Oracle merge JRockIt and the Standard JDK?

Tags: java, jrockit

I just want to know as it does seem like they have duplication of effort in maintaining two JDKs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes that's the plan, they intend to use hotspot as the basis for the merged jvm and I believe they plan to build in some of the tooling that jrockit provides. Details in [this blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/2010/11/oracles_jvm_strategy.html)

Answer (score 2):

Not that Wikipedia's the most reliable source, but it seems to suggest that they will be merging them:

> Following the finalization of the acquisition of Sun Microsystems, Oracle announced in its January 27, 2010, Strategy Update webcast that the best features of JRockit would be implemented in the Java 7 JVM.([ref](http://eventreg.oracle.com/webapps/events/ns/EventsDetail.jsp?p_eventId=108481&src=6806472&src=6806472&Act=22))

I'd say this is probably a good thing, though in practice I was always sceptical of how many real-world performance improvements JRockit actually provided.

Comment: I'm just glad they aren't trying to merge them into an update of java6